# include the node_modules in my visual studio project

Tags: angular

I have created the application using angularjs 2, now I have to check in that in my svn,for this I have to include the node_modules folder in my project.But it is failing after doing include in my project.
Is there any command to run so that I can include it in one step?

Comment: After including the node_modules folder in my project, i am getting the error as  Property 'exception' does not exist on type 'Notification<number>'.

Comment: May I include the node_modules folder in my project?